# Andengine game restarts on mobile screen off

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing game in 'andengine'. When i off screen when playing game.and again start the screen and open screen lock then game starting from start.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: When you unlock the screen the onResume method gets called so again all your resources get loaded and all data are reset. Thats why your game start from beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to just put Following line in to your main activity tag in mainifest file.
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard"